# libxml2-2.9.12.tar.gz AND libgit2-1.3.0.tar.gz are not available for this version of R==4.1 and causing packages dependent on them to fail

Tags: r, libxml2, devtools, libgit2, xml2

Utilizing R version 4.1.0 on a linux-gnu system.  RStudio version 1.4.1717. No internet connection.

I have been trying to get xml2 and devtools packages installed, however, since it is saying that the dependencies libxml2-2.9.12.tar.gz AND libgit2-1.3.0.tar.gz are not available for this version of R, I don't know what to do.    Just selecting Tools>Install Packages > Install from CRAN, xml2 or gert, or whatever other package have these two packages as a dependency, gives me an ANTICONF ERROR.

> ------------------------ANTICONF ERROR----------------------------
>
> Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
>
> *rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, Centos, RHEL)
>
> -----------------------[ERROR MESSAGE]----------------------------
>
> stdin:1:18: fatal error: git2.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated

It is not already installed, so I don't need to check for it in my PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH.
Whether I install the package that is dependent on it and check that I want to install dependencies as well, or specifically try to install each package and the dependencies manually, I can't get through this error. All attempts remove the failed package I tried to install.

I can't find any indicator online as to why this is happening.  Doesn't make sense that the dependency isn't available if the package is available. Any thoughts to get these packages and their dependencies installed?

Comment: CRAN keeps packages for the _current_ version of R at its repo. You are a version and release year behind.  You can still install those from source as you tried but you need to also install the build-dependencies -- as the error shows.  So install `libxml2-devel` with `yum` or `dnf` or whatever you use to install _system_ packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had to run, from a terminal,  "sudo yum libgit2-devel" and "sudo yum libxml2-devel" in order for "install.packages("devtools")" and "install.packages("xml2")" to install successfully in RStudio. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is what I suggested. Glad it helped, and you're up and running now.